# Best practice for a REST-ful API where objects would naturally have a "/" in their identifier

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I am designing a **REST api** for a **document management system**. To make the API more natural, I thought about using the natural identifier for a file, which is it's path (usually having forward slashes "/" in it), and not something like an artificial id such as a UUID.

Naturally, a user would identify a file by it's path:

```
/path/to/file.txt
```

Unfortunately, this clashes with common, good API design.

This would work:

```
Retrieving a file: GET /api/v1/files/<path/to/file.txt>
```

However, other methods you would like to have, will become a bit problematic:

```
Retrieving a file list of a folder: GET /api/v1/folders/<path/to/folder>/files
```

My thoughts so far:

- avoid unique identifiers with "/" in it entirely, and use an artificial UUID (such as Alfresco is using NodeId / NodeRefs). This would add another layer of abstraction to it, where a unique id is just not very natural from a business domain perspective
- don't use the identifier in the url path but in a parameter (against good API design patterns)
- (requesting the API users to replace the / with another character is of course also not an option)

Of course, files and folders as we know it from a file system, are naturally identified by it's path. In that particular case, one could argue that if someone wants to use the path as the identifier, than the correct way for doing:

```
Retrieving a file: GET /api/v1/files/<path/to/file.txt>
```

would actually be:

```
Retrieving a file: GET /api/v1/folders/<path>/folders/<to>/files/<file.txt>
```

if we want to be really correct here.

**Update: I want to ask the community about best practices and experiences here - especially when Dropbox and Google Drive both use two different approaches (see first answer and comments below): DropBox is using the path while Google Drive is using IDs.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may wish to look into [Google Drive API's](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) way of handling this. In their case, paths are abstractions and files are selected by id.

A file is a resource.
It can belong to a folder, so it has a 'Parents' property. It can belong to multiple folders (either as a shared item, or to simulate soft-links), so it can have multiple 'Parents'.
It can be moved to a different "folder", in which case the actual resource does not change location -- its parents property is just changed. The filename is not used in the URI, because an id is unique and a string can have odd characters.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Google Drive API. Yes, it's the same concept that Alfresco is also using with the NodeRef/NodeId. The renaming case is a good point, which makes sense.

Comment: Interestingly, the Dropbox API uses the path as well (as in my OP) as url path variables. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

Comment: Using file paths directly seems like the biggest soon-to-be-headache imaginable. Any time a user wants to change a file location you have to change the literal file location? Recipe for disaster. Unique ids are better, because a file is an object, and objects have properties such as *parent* and *children[]*. Why bother with file paths at all in your API? Ids are easy (especially for your API consumers to keep track of!).

Answer (score 2):

Forget about files for a moment.

You have an API, and at some point you need to insert identifiers specific to your application. Since your application isn't primarily interested in the features of the API, and because these identifiers are determined without even knowing about the API, you need to be able to translate an arbitrary identifier into something that the API can handle.

There is a standard mechanism for this, which is percent encoding. It handles all these pesky cases like identifiers containing slashes, less than and greater.  For example, on my Mac, `/"what</do">you think/"about>>this` is a perfectly valid path with the three path components `"what<`, `do">you think`, and `"about>>this`. Percent encoding has no problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

First of this

```
/api/v1/someresource
```

is not actually good REST api design. The version of the api should not be in the path of a resource. A resource is just a resource. The version of the data structure representing the resource should be in the MIME time. For example when you go to a webpage you don't have URLs like this

```
www.newyorktimes.com/html5/headlines
www.newyorktimes.com/html2.1/headlines
```

you just have this

```
www.newyorktimes.com/headlines
```

And the browser figures out if it can display HTML5 or HTML2 or XML or what ever the search reports it can return for that resource. The version of HTML used is in the meta information for the representation of the resource `headlines`.

So don't do that with your API either. If there is a version 1 of a resource and a version 2 of that resource record that in the mime time of the resource. If you are expecting the client to know the location of resources based on the version of the API you are also not following REST. You should be able to move a resource to another location without having to up the API version.

There is nothing wrong then with the URI

```
www.myserver.com/files/path/to/file.txt
```

or even just

```
www.myserver.com/path/to/file.txt
```

if that makes sense with regard to how you want to structure your resources. This is how static files are served on a web server and it has worked fine for decades.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get google explicitely has the version of the api in the resource api...

Comment: Loads of people do it, doesn't mean it is a good idea. Imagine you use Drive. Imagine you store say a jpeg in Drive. From your point of view (the client) what is the difference between "v1" and "v2" of your resource? Literally nothing. So why has your URL changed? The reason companies do this is because they don't put navigation information into the hypertext representations (HATEOS), so clients have to memorize URL schemas via documentation to do anything. Then api devs change their minds, and you have to re-write the client with a new set of URLs.